# How to avoid duplicate labels on each tile?

Tags: geoserver

When I display my map using tiles a label gets drawn on each tile - is there any way to avoid this?

I have attached an example image to show the problem:

[image]

Comment: some of your question seems to be missing

Comment: Single label shows in multiple.(Example: Block 43 shows in several times when zoomed layers)

Answer (score 8):

Use meta-tiling http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#tiled

Answer (score 8):

with this code...

```
<TextSymbolizer>
   <Geometry>
      <ogc:Function name="centroid">
         <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
      </ogc:Function>
   </Geometry>
</TextSymbolizer>
```

Comment: Can you explain how that works?