# Issues with atlas generator and labelling across maps/images

Tags: qgis, labeling, tiles, print-composer, atlas-generator

I have a lot of layers in my project and I am trying to use the *atlas generator* in the *print composer* to create a tiled map. Some of the layers have labels which have different configurations with respect to placement.

So far I have found that only the placement *offset from centroid* with the *centroid* option *whole polygon* selected works seamlessly when exporting to tiles. In the following images four neighboring tiles has been merged and the blue lines represents the tile borders:

**Offset from centroid:**
[image: Offset from centroid]

**Around centroid:**
[image: Around centroid]

**Free:**
[image: Free]

**Using perimeter:**
[image: Using perimeter]

The labels looks fine in QGIS when viewing the different areas, but every label is placed automatically to give a good visual appearance based on the current view. In my case the *current view* should be the entire map and each tile should be rendered according to that view.

**Question:**
Is it possible to configure the label engine in the atlas generator to calculate the label placements for the entire map instead of each tile separately?

Comment: Make point label layer.

Comment: @nagib, can you elaborate a bit on that idea? I have thousands of features with labels belonging to points, lines and polygons. Since the label engine only determine the placement/transformation of each label on rendering, I would manually need to decide how each label should be placed and how it should be rendered. I think it kinda defeats the purpose of the label engine.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37138/polygon-label-repeated-for-each-tile - the only solution is to tell QGis where to place each label exactly as the label engine only sees the tile.

Comment: You might want to look into a different method of generating tiles in QGIS, such as those recommended here: gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14087/how-to-generate-tiles-with-qgis