# How to make labels appear in Geoserver? (WMS)

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, labeling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid duplicate labels on each tile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29127/how-to-avoid-duplicate-labels-on-each-tile)

I have an Annotation Shapefile. I added it into GeoServer as point Shapefile and set its label with the help of the style parameter. But the problem is the labels don't appear at start up. The labels only appear after a lot of zooming in. Is there a solution for this? Like how labels appear in Arc Map?
Here is the [sld](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/_downloads/point_pointwithdefaultlabel.sld).

Comment: please add (some of) your sld file to the question so we can see what might be happening.

Comment: @iant please check it out

Comment: Your SLD is fine - we'll need to know more about how you are displaying it - are tiles involved?

Comment: @iant Yes tiles are involved

Comment: @iant Not quite. The problem on that case was that the labels appear on each polygon. In this one, labels don't appear at all.

Comment: The solution is the same though

Comment: @muzaffar Please show us the SLD..

Comment: @Sunil SLD is present at the very last of Question.